# Flatten nested JSON struct with dynamic keys in PySpark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to process json files with **PySpark** that contain a struct column with dynamic keys.

The schema of the struct column looks like this:

```
{
  "UUID_KEY": {
     "time": STRING
     "amount": INTEGER
  }
}
```

The data looks like this:

| id | json_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "{1: {amount: 1, time: 2}, 2: {amount: 10, time: 5}}" |
| 2 | "{3: {amount: 1, time: 2}, 4: {amount: 10, time: 5}" |

Currently I have the struct columns as a **string**, since loading the JSON with specifying / inferring the schema does **not** work as the keys of the first layer are randomly generated and there is just too much data. The second layer is always the same, it contains `amount` and `time`.

Is there a way of flatting this JSON string into `amount` and `time` columns, without knowing the key of the first layer?

Comment: Currently the json_column is just a string, right?

Comment: Yes, I can only read it by explicitly casting it to string in the schema during read. If Spark tries to infer it it just runs indefinitely, and manually specifying the StructType schema is impossible.

Comment: Got it. Added my answer, let me know if the requirement is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work:

```
map_schema=MapType(StringType(), StructType([\
    StructField('amount', StringType(), True),\
    StructField('time', StringType(),True)\
]));

df\
.withColumn("json_column", F.from_json(F.col("json_column"), map_schema, {"allowUnquotedFieldNames":"true"}))\
.select("*", F.explode("json_column").alias("key", "value"))\
.select("id", "value.*")\
.show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

```
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|id |json_column                                        |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{1: {amount: 1, time: 2}, 2: {amount: 10, time: 5}}|
|2  |{3: {amount: 1, time: 2}, 4: {amount: 10, time: 5}}|
+---+---------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- json_column: string (nullable = true)
```

Output:

```
+---+------+----+
|id |amount|time|
+---+------+----+
|1  |1     |2   |
|1  |10    |5   |
|2  |1     |2   |
|2  |10    |5   |
+---+------+----+
```

Comment: Oh my god, I've been using Spark for so long and I hadn't heard of MapType until today. Thank you so much! :)